# Visual Studio IDE - how to hide/remove window main buttons?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to hide/remove these buttons in `Visual Studio IDE` (especially `Close` button):

[image]

I can still call them from context menu so I don't need them:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. For what reason are you wanting to?

Comment: VS is very non user friendly (for me as VSCode user). if i suddenly close the window  then it is challenge for me to restore it :)

Comment: _"VS is very non user friendly"_ The more time you spend using it, the more you will get used to it and you will soon get used to knowing how to find/reopen closed windows. It's a much more capable IDE than VS Code which is, at it's heart, a very capable text editor.

Comment: I've been using one version or another of VS for the last 15 years or so and don't find myself accidentally closing stuff. If anything, I have the opposite problem and end up with a lot of windows open that I use briefly to accomplish a specific goal but ends up being left open.|

Answer (score 1):

It's a best effort scenario. So, you can arrange your windows and make some little settings to kind of simulate what you want. Here's what you have to do:

Lets take solution explorer as an example

1. Move solution explorer as a tab, next to your files. You can drag it there or, right click it, and select Dock as tabbed document
   [image]
   [image]

It's no longer in dock, it's a tab

2. Now we're going to modify some tab settings. Right click any tab, set tab layout and then click options
   [image]
3. You're after Show pin button in unpinned tabs and Show close button on document tabs
   [image]

There's one more thing to do to finish

4. Take the solution explorer tab and drag it so that it will be on the half of the code file
   [image]
   then all that's left to do is to resize your new side by side view

---

You can add multiple "non-code" tabs there, and navigate through them using the little arrow on the right

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it's absolutely not usable :)